# pass data from state to new action in rxjs effect

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I want to access state data to pass the results as properties of a new action. I managed to extract the required data from the state after the effect is triggered but the final part dispatching the new action using data isn´t working. I can´t pass the two arguments `activeUser` and `activeTask` to the `of(GetInstances({activeUser, activeTask}))` part in the last line of code.

```
@Effect()
updateInstanceLabelSuccess$ = this._actions$.pipe(
  ofType<Action>(EInstanceActions.UpdateInstanceLabelSuccess),
  concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(combineLatest(
      [this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveUser)),
        this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveTask))]
    ))
  )),
  tap(([action, [activeUser, activeTask]]: [Action, [User, Task]]) => {
    console.log(activeUser, activeTask);
    // activeUer and activeTask successfully loaded
    // pass activeUser + activeTask to props of Action GetInstances
  }),
  // activeUser and activeTask can´t be passed to new GetInstances Action
  switchMap(([action, [activeUser, activeTask]]: [Action, [User, Task]]) => of(GetInstances({activeUser, activeTask})))
);
```

How is it possible to pass the two parameters `activeUser` and `activeTask` to a new `GetInstances` Action?

**EDIT:**

I got it working with the following code. Is this a valid solution for the problem?

```
@Effect()
updateInstanceLabelSuccess$ = this._actions$.pipe(
  ofType<Action>(EInstanceActions.UpdateInstanceLabelSuccess),
  concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(combineLatest(
      [this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveUser)),
      this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveTask))]
    ))
  )),
  map(([action, [activeUser, activeTask]]: [Action, [User, Task]]) => GetInstances({userID: activeUser.id, taskID: activeTask.id}))
);
```

Comment: Do you get an error or does the action just not have any payload?

Comment: For the updated question: your implementation seems fine to me, great it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

That code looks great, and is a perfectly valid way to do it.

Unless I'm missing something, I think you could clean things up like:

```
@Effect()
updateInstanceLabelSuccess$ = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Action>(EInstanceActions.UpdateInstanceLabelSuccess),
    withLatestFrom(
        this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveUser)),
        this._userStore.pipe(select(selectActiveTask)),
        (action, activeUser, activeTask) => [activeUser, activeTask]
    ),
    map(([activeUser, activeTask]): [User, Task]) => GetInstances({userID: activeUser.id, taskID: activeTask.id}))
);
```

All I'm doing here is taking advantage of the overloads of [withLatestFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom), including a final projection function, which I find useful in these situations where you don't want to carry around the extraneous Action.

Another suggestion is to create a new selector that combines those 2 you have. I know that sounds like overkill, but doing it that way gives you a small performance advantage due to the built-in caching of selector results.

Anyway, I hope that helps. Nice work on figuring that out.

Comment: Your code looks very clean and is working well, thank you for the tips